# how to name my android package if I do not have a site

Tags: android, package

I've read much about android package naming conventions, but still have no idea what I should name my packages if I don't have any personal webpage whatsoever and am not a member of any organization. Open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply using your name? <strike>(In camelCase, as seems to be the Java convention)</strike> I assume that's what you'd be publishing your apps under (as you're not a member of any organisation), so why not name your package com.myname.myapp?

Edit: see comments

Comment: By Java conventions, package names must be lowercase.

Comment: I went with this using lowercase letters and my app dev pseudonym.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
    com.myapp."Name of your app"
```

or anyhing of this nature. Just make sure its something you want to stick with. 
[Check here: This may be of help](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

Hope this helps

Another possible scheme if you have a company:

```
com.<name-of-your-company>.android.<name-of-the-app>
```

Comment: Agreed.  I've been going with com.mygmailhandle.myapp

Comment: Yeah thats usually the best way to do it. If you have a company com."name of your app dev company"."name of the app"

Comment: Another possible scheme if you have a company: com.<name-of-your-company>.android.<name-of-the-app>

Comment: @Giulio Piancastelli Good Suggestion